# TransformJsx.proj Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, reactjs.net

I am adding ReactJS to a new ASP.NET MVC site, that I have been working on. From NuGet, I installed the "ReactJS.Net (MVC 4 and 5)" package. 
 When I tried running the the code, I get errors pointing to the TransformJsx.proj on the element "TransformJsx".

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="TransformJsx">
       <!-- ReactJS.NET - Transforms JSX to JavaScript -->
       <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(OutputPath)\React.MSBuild.dll" TaskName="TransformJsx" />
       <Target Name="TransformJsx">
          <TransformJsx SourceDir="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
       </Target>
    </Project>
```

the errors are

- The "TransformJsx" task failed unexpectedly. C:\Users\310171329\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TeamManagement\TeamManagement\TransformJsx.proj    6   3   TeamManagement
- React.Exceptions.JsxException: Parse Error: Line 9: Unexpected token > (at line 9 column 25) ---> JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsRuntimeException: Parse Error: Line 9: Unexpected token > (at line 9 column 25) ---> MsieJavaScriptEngine.JsRuntimeException: Parse Error: Line 9: Unexpected token > (at line 9 column 25)    C:\Users\310171329\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TeamManagement\TeamManagement\TransformJsx.proj    6   3   TeamManagement

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This normally means there's a syntax error in your JavaScript file. Did you try looking at what's at line 9 character 25 of the .js file?

Comment: There was a syntax error in the jsx file. The coordinates of the error were for the generated js file. this might have been due to the comments added to the top of the file. Which adds an extra 5 lines to my code.